# What critical analysis has been published on Logosophy?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

I came across [Logosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logosophy) for the first time today and I’m struggling to find any analysis of it. The Wikipedia article seems quite promotional, and does not link to any critical sources - at least, not in the English language.

It seems superficially similar to Scientology, but predating it and popular mostly in Latin America.

“Logosophy is an ethical-philosophical doctrine developed by the Argentine humanist and thinker Carlos Bernardo González Pecotche, which offers teachings of conceptual order and practices that lead oneself to self-cognition and self-improvement through a process of conscious evolution.”

I am interested in how much of this is new thought, how coherent it is, and what it has influenced since its emergence in the 1930s.

Comment: Wikipedia editors did some searching for peer review and did not find much when the Logosophy article was up for a [deletion vote](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Wikipedia:Articles_for_deletion/Logosophy). One of the editors who voted to keep it wrote:"Sure it sounds dumb, but so does Theosophy and we have an article on that. This kind of claptrap is big business in Argentina".

Comment: I have read some about Logosophy. If you send me your email I can try to help. What do you need information for? Regards.